# Sql substring_index remove non-permalink addresses

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get all the results in my database that match a specific query.

Right now the way I have it is basically selecting only the root domain.

For example I have in my database:

www.website.com/hello
www.website.com/

I only select www.website.com/ right now but instead I want to select only domains that have something after the slash (/) and display them in a table.

Here is my code - I tried adding things before and after the '/' and playing around with the number '3' or '-3' but nothing gives me the result I want.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) FROM crawldomains;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT url FROM crawldomains WHERE `url` RLIKE '^(http://|https://)?.*\\..*/.+$'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This just selected everything in the database.

Comment: Yes - how do I change it so that it would work with it?